# How would I create a page that changes its info depending on the button clicked?

Tags: php

What I have is 12 images that are coupons, and each one is meant for each month. 
I have it so the site will find out the date, and the image that has the name of what month it is, will be posted.
I also have it so it shows the next 2 months' images.

So I have 3 images that will change each month, and what I would like it to do is when someone clicks one of the image, it brings you to an info page. I want the info page's content to change depending on what image they pick.

I am really stuck on how to do this and I would like some ideas on what would be the best way to do it?

Thanks!
I am using PHP

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="info.php?month=1"><img src="your_image.jpg" /></a>
```

and in your info.php page

```
<?php
switch ($_GET["month"]) {
    case '0':
        echo "some content";
        break;
    case '1':
        echo "some other content";
        break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the images link to URLs like `infoscript.php?couponid=123` and fetch the `couponid` in PHP this way (in the `infoscript.php` or whatever you name it):

```
$couponid = $_GET["couponid"];
settype($couponid, "integer");
```

This assumes that all couponids are numbers.